# JSDoc to handle Rhino's importPackage

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, rhino

In Rhino, one can do

```
importPackage(Packages.foo.bar.xyzzy);
```

This imports in the current namespace all the members of the Java foo.bar.xyzzy class.

I've already set up Typescript declaration files for that class so I can use

```
var x = Packages.foo.bar.xyzzy.memberA;
var y = Packages.foo.bar.xyzzy.memberB;
```

and get completion, type checking etc in VSCode (and the typescript that it uses)

With that importPackage, I can use

```
var z = memberA;
```

and it works (at run time) but VSCode complains because it has no idea that `importPackage` means that the members are imported.

Can I add some JSDoc that will cause VSCode to know that? It's a sort of

```
 import * from Packages.foo.bar.xyzzy
```

I guess

EDIT:

```
class xyzzy extends Packages.foo.bar.xyzzy {}
```

gets me close, but two problems: Rhino doesn't support class (so I need it to be in a JSDoc comment instead) and it means I can do `xyzzy.methodY()` now, but not just `methodY()`

My typescript-fu isn't that strong so I'm not really sure how to go about this

Comment: i'm not sure about this but you're using typescript right?

Comment: @TachibanaShin No. Rhino does Javascript only, and that's what I'm writing. I can put typescript in .d.ts files (which are used just as references while editing), and JSDoc comments in my Javascript. But we're not transpiling TS to JS

Comment: mean you are using javascript and running it with rhino and you want to define the types using typescript ?

Comment: Exactly. And mostly, this works (I have a lot of .d.ts files for the Java packages I use). I just want to support ImportPackage in VSCode too.

Comment: i'm not sure about rhino but if you want to import styles in typescript or jsdoc you will need `import { <props> } from '<path to file>'` or `import Name from '<path ot file>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid, there is no way to do what you want via typescript + jsdoc.
`importPackage` works like a [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement. It modifies current execution context. TypeScript itself doesn't support types for `with`. Also, JavaScript doesn't have such conception as `import * from "foo"` (The correct one `import * as foo from "foo"`).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That was my thought but I'm not a typescript expert.  In our context, importPackage is also a performance issue so best-practice is to avoid using it, hence fixing this isn't essential but it would  have been nice.